# PHP mysql query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

This is the query code:

```
if (isset($_POST['moduleAction']) && ($_POST['moduleAction'] == 'edit')) {

            $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());                
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE todolist SET what = ?, priority = ?, added_on = ? WHERE id = ?');
            $stmt->execute(array($what, $priority + 1, $date, $id));

    }
```

My db connection:

```
<?php

    try {
        $db = new PDO('mysql:host=' . DB_HOST .';dbname=' . DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8mb4', DB_USER, DB_PASS);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        showDbError('connect', $e->getMessage());
    }
```

The query is not executed on the db, on another page in the same document i am executing queries to the same db without problem. I've tried executing it without a prepared statement, double quotes, restarting te connection,... nothing works.

Anyone who can push me in the right direction?

**EDIT**

Setting variables:

```
$priorities = array('low','normal','high'); // The possible priorities of a todo
    $formErrors = array(); // The encountered form errors

    $id = isset($_GET['id']) ? (int) $_GET['id'] : 0; // The passed in id of the todo

    $what = isset($_POST['what']) ? $_POST['what'] : ''; // The todo that was sent in via the form
    $priority = isset($_POST['priority']) ? $_POST['priority'] : 'low'; // The priority that was sent in via the form
```

Comment: In your extract you're not setting `$what`, `$priority`, or `$id`. Where do those variables get set?

Answer (score 0):

If your query is not execute and you get no error I would say that something is wrong with this

```
if(isset($_POST['moduleAction']) && ($_POST['moduleAction'] == 'edit')) {
```

Make sure your moduleAction is set in your post array and is really egal to 'edit'.

Hope this helps

Comment: No problem with the if statement, when I place an echo inside it, php echo's it.

Answer (score 0):

You should always check for errors, there is so many reason an query fail to work as expected.

Here is the right way to check:

```
 if(isset($_POST['moduleAction']) && ($_POST['moduleAction'] == 'edit')) {
   $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
   $query ='UPDATE todolist SET what = ?, priority = ?, added_on = ? WHERE id = ?';   
   if($stmt = $db->prepare($query)){
        if($stmt->execute(array($what, $priority + 1, $date, $id))){
            echo 'execute() successful';
            if($stmt->rowCount() > 0){
                echo 'Affected a row';
            }else{
                echo 'No row affected';
            }
        }else{
            echo 'execute() error:';
            die($dbh->errorInfo());
        }
    }else{
        echo 'prepare() error:';
        die($dbh->errorInfo()); 
    }
}
```

---

**Edit**

One more thing, `$priority + 1` seem a little weird.

After your update I see this line:

```
$priority = isset($_POST['priority']) ? $_POST['priority'] : 'low';
```

so you try to increment a string by 1?

Anyway what happened to traditional debugging  ?

```
$sql_debug = "UPDATE todolist 
              SET what = '$what', priority = '$priority', added_on = '$date' 
              WHERE id = $id";

echo "**************************************<br>";
echo $sql_debug."<br>";
echo "**************************************<br>";

error_log('sql = '.$sql_debug);
```

Take a look at the query

And run to see what happens

Comment: When executing your code above, php echo's: execute() successfulNo row affected

Comment: then this tells you it is not code related, see update

Comment: That means that you just have no todolist in your database that match the id you want to update.

Comment: if it's not code related, then what could it be?  my db? because i'm executing queries on it via the terminal and another php page.

Comment: @holygrinder exactly, this means `@user3165926` needs to close the PHP file, and go investigate the db

Comment: And i defenitly have that id available, i've checked that manually

Comment: @user3165926 see my edited answer , I have expanded on how you can troubleshoot further hope that helps

Comment: I am curious about that Id, Can you add echo "$id updated"; after your execute and tell us the output.

Answer (score 0):

I think update query is correct,please check the date time format,try this code

```
 if (isset($_POST['moduleAction']) && ($_POST['moduleAction'] == 'edit')) {

            $date=date_create("2014-10-09");
            date_time_set($date,13,24,46);         
            $datetime =date_format($date,"Y-m-d H:i:s");                
            $stmt = $db->prepare('UPDATE todolist SET what = ?, priority = ?, added_on = ? WHERE id = ?');
            $stmt->execute(array($what, $priority + 1, $datetime, $id));

    }
```